# How do I resolve this error adding a new performance category in windows 7

Tags: c#, performance, permissions, performancecounter

I am trying to write some c# code that writes a new Performance Counter Category if it doesn't exist, and then adds a specific counter. When I run this code from the Visual Studio dev server, everything works fine. When I deploy it to IIS and try it, I get permission errors. I am running Windows 7 and using IIS 7.5.

What I have done so far, some of which is being done out of desperation:

1. Created a new App Pool that I will run as a specific user
2. Created a new user and added him to the Process Monitor and Administrator groups
3. Set the new user as the identity of the new App Pool
4. Pointed my web service to that App Pool.
5. Went in to regedit and gave the user full control over HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet (apparently there should be a permissions folder, but I don't see it anywhere).

I know these steps have worked partially, because I am now able to check whether or not a category exists (ASPNET user couldn't even do that). I can check if a category exists, I just cant add a new one.

The error that I get is

```
Cannot create or delete the Performance Category 'C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp1AA8.tmp' because access is denied.
```

The code to add the performance counter category is looks like this:

```
         if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("APIService"))
            {
                CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

                CounterCreationData counter = new CounterCreationData();
                counter.CounterName = "# of operations executed";
                counter.CounterHelp = "Operations executed";
                counter.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond32;

                counters.Add(counter);
                PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("APIService", "Api Counter", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, counters); // This code blows up

            }
```

I have searched high and low and cant find anyone with the same problem. I have even tried giving Everyone Full Control over c:\windows\temp. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the solution (or rather someone else did, but I can find a link to that forum this morning). Instead of setting the App Pool to run as an admin, I switched it to the Local System user. That seems to have resolved everything, as the user has sufficient rights to write performance metrics and everything else that needs to be done.